# What is the intersection of a non-existiant set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $A$, Is the following true?
$$\not \exists B \implies A \cap B = \emptyset$$

Comment: It is quite meaningless to write $\lnot \exists B$...

Comment: Obviously, if set $B$ does not exists, it has no "name" and thus we cannot use its name to write the name of the intersection of $A$ with the non-existent set.

Comment: It is like saying: John dos not exists and Fred is his father.

Comment: What the comments of @MauroALLEGRANZA indicate is that there is no way to assign a meaningful interpretation of what you have written.  Note that the following revised assertion, which you might have intended to express, is *meaningful*, though false: $\neg (\exists B)~$ such that for any set $(A),~(A\cap B) = \emptyset.$  While this *revised*  assertion is false, and refuted by $(B = \emptyset)$, the assertion is still meaningful.

Comment: For what its worth, I disagree with both the downvote and the votes to close, and therefore upvoted the query from (-1) back to 0.  The reason that I disagree, is that the original poster (OP) is *legitimately* confused about the proper use of the implication sign ($\implies$).  This means that what he is *really* asking is whether he has used the implication sign correctly.  I regard this as a perfectly legitimate question that other responses to this query have addressed.

Answer (score 1):

Given some set $A$, you can write

$$ \not\exists B, A\cap B = \emptyset$$

The above is a formula expressing that "there is no set $B$ such that its intersection with $A$ is empty". However, the formula is not valid (choose $B=\emptyset$).

For the formula that you write in your question, the missing parentheses could be placed as in $\not\exists B (\implies A\cap B=\emptyset)$ or as in $(\not\exists B)\implies A\cap B=\emptyset$. Either way, none of the two parenthesized formulas make sense.
In the first case, the formula is syntactically not correct. In the second case, the $B$ in $A\cap B$ is not necessarily the same as the $B$ in $\not\exists B$.
In both cases, the formulas make no sense.